# how an application works which runs on one phone with one resolution, then runs on another phone with a different resolution

Tags: android

how an application works which runs on one phone with one resolution, then runs on another phone with a different resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are referring to is "how will an app run on different screen sizes".

Its pretty simple actually. When you are designing an app, design it to support multiple screen sizes. Use this link as a reference.

[Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)